# Elementwise comparison of numpy arrays to yield output arrays

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

We have several "in_arrays" like

`in_1=np.array([0.4,0.7,0.8,0.3])`

`in_2=np.array([0.9,0.8,0.6,0.4])`

I need to create two outputs like

`out_1=np.array([0,0,1,0])`

`out_2=np.array([1,1,0,0])`

So, the given element of the output array is 1 if the value in the corresponding input array is greater than 0.5 AND the value in this position of this input array is greater than the values of other arrays in this position. What is the efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate all the input arrays in a single matrix, where each row represents a particular input array. That way it is possible to calculate all the output arrays again as a single matrix.

The code could look something like that:

```
import numpy as np

# input matrix corresponding to the example input arrays given in the question
in_matrix = np.array([[0.4,0.7,0.8,0.3], [0.9,0.8,0.6,0.4]])

out_matrix = np.zeros(in_matrix.shape)

# each element in the array is the maximal value of the corresponding column in input_matrix
max_values = np.max(in_matrix, axis=0) 

# compute the values in the output matrix row by row
for n, row in enumerate(in_matrix):
    out_matrix[n] = np.logical_and(row > 0.5, row == max_values)
```